# how to send arraylist<hashmap<string, string>> value from fragmentactivity to fragment for listview

Tags: java, android

please help me with this..
anyone please tell me how to send an arraylist> value from fragmentactivity to its fragment as from this value i have to create listview using simple adapter..
before this i have send the value from activity to fragmentactivity using putExtra(string, serializable) then fetching it in fragmentactivity using getintent.getSerializable extra..but after that i don't know hwo to use this value is fragment for list view..

This is mainactivity from where i am sending the value

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();


        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pager.class);
        i.putExtra("DATALIST", datatList);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bundle Value" +datatList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(i);
```

this is pager extends fragmentactivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("DATALIST");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bundle Value in pager" +data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

now i want to use "data value " in fragment of pager from listview please explain how..

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should create class like .

```
 public class Data
  {
  public static final Arraylist<Hashmap<String,String>> map;

   }
```

when you redirect to other page

```
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pager.class);

    Data.map = datatList;//assign here
    startActivity(i);
```

after redirect to other page

```
 data = Data.map;// get here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just pass the same bundle to fragment when you create it like:

in onCreate or in the getItem of the pager adapter(if you are using it)

```
Frag2 dv=new Frag2 ();
dv.setArguments(getIntent().getBundle());
```

and in `onCreateView` of the fragment

```
 data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getArguments().getSerializableExtra("DATALIST");
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bundle Value in pager" +data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: pager is the class which extends fragmentactivity where i am able to get the arraylist<hashmap<string,string>> value which is sent by the main activity...

Comment: so where are you creating fragment?? are you using ViewPager or just simply calling replace on FragmentManager?? or Have a fragment in xml and trying to send this data to that fragment??

Comment: i am using android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in xml and class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter for fragments..where pager is the class which extends fragmentactivity..

Comment: please help me with it i really stuck in it for a along time...i have used the example for fragments from here..[link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)